# Chrome Extension Desktop Notification Works On Sleep

Tags: google-chrome-extension, notifications, sleep

I made a Desktop Notification it shows a notification every 1 minute. After 10  second,  closes itself.

I gone for a lunch , then computer goes to sleep. When i was back i wake my computer then lots of notification starts.

How can i handle that problem? I want if computer sleeps it shouldnt show notification. How can i control it?

**Background.js**

```
function show() {

   var notification = webkitNotifications.createHTMLNotification(
  'notification.html'  
);

  notification.show();
}

// Conditionally initialize the options.
if (!localStorage.isInitialized) {
  localStorage.isActivated = true;   // The display activation.
  localStorage.frequency = 1;        // The display frequency, in minutes.
  localStorage.isInitialized = true; // The option initialization.
}


if (window.webkitNotifications) {
  // While activated, show notifications at the display frequency.

  if (JSON.parse(localStorage.isActivated)) { show(); }

  var interval = 0; // The display interval, in minutes.


  setInterval(function() {
  interval++;     
  chrome.idle.queryState(15, state); 
  if(localStorage.frequency <= interval && state=="active")
     { show(); 
       interval = 0;
     }

  }, 60000);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Chrome.idle` API to detect whether browser is active or not and trigger your notifications. I guess you can use a configurable interval to query state and hold off your notifications.

## Reference

- [Chrome.idle](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/idle.html#method-queryState)

## EDIT 1

The state in your code is a callback function, not a string!, So change this code

```
setInterval(function () {
    chrome.idle.queryState(15, state);
    if (localStorage.frequency <= interval && state == "active") {
        show();
        interval = 0;
    }

}, 60000);
```

to

```
setInterval(function () {
    chrome.idle.queryState(15, function (state) {
        if (localStorage.frequency <= interval && state == "active") {
            show();
            interval = 0;
        }

    });
}, 60000);
```

Comment: hi this page says "chrome.idle.queryState(integer thresholdSeconds, function callback) Returns the current state of the browser." But when  i use it extension doesnt works. 

My code like:
chrome.idle.queryState(15, state);
if(state=="active"){
open();
}

Comment: @MuratCihan:Can you put your present state of code by editing question, it will be easier for me to identify problem.

Comment: @MuratCihan: Check my **EDIT 1**, this should solve your problem.

Comment: maybe wrong place for this Q, but I would like to ensure that notifications are shown when the computer wakes up from sleep. This behavior isn't consistent: sometimes the notifications come on after sleep, sometimes they don't. Is the default behavior for them to come on upon wake-up and I have a problem when they don't or is it the other way around?