# chrome extension - stop multiple notifications from appearing simultaneously

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, notifications, web-worker

I can't figure out how to stop my chrome extension from simultaneously showing multiple notifications.  currently, the extension allows users to set up to 5 alarm times that will cause a generic notification to appear.

The problem arises when I set multiple alarms and then put my Mac to sleep. If I wake the computer after the alarm time passed, followed by another 10-20 seconds, all of the notifications show up at the same time on the screen:

The console for the background page shows that these notifications appeared within milliseconds of one another, even though they were triggered by alarms that were a minute apart.

[image: screenshot of console log]

I've written some simple code that clears outstanding notifications that are pending before showing a new notification, but this code doesn't stop this special case of when the computer was asleep.  (it does work for other situations where simultaneous notifications appeared retroactively, like when the user is full screen with another application and returns to chrome.)

Here is my code to delete "pending" notifications:

```
chrome.notifications.getAll(function(notifications) {
  // clear out any notifications already pending so there's no dupes!
  Object.keys(notifications).forEach(function(notificationID) {
    console.log("clearing notification ID: " + notificationID);
    chrome.notifications.clear(notificationID);
  });
});
```

I'm not sure how chrome is handling notifications and alarms in the background. Any help shedding light on how to stop notifications from appearing simultaneously would be great.

Comment: Check if the alarm time is less than the current time in onAlarm callback and don't show anything if expired.

Comment: But what's the expected behavior? You don't want any notification to appear or just one ?

Comment: Expected behavior is just one notification showing, eliminating any duplicates.  @wOxxOm, thanks for the tip, I'll look into the onAlarm callback and see if that works!   Hosar, your question could be right on, I may need to tweak things to ensure at least one notification gets displayed.

Comment: after additional research, i found this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14458019/chrome-extension-desktop-notification-works-on-sleep) as a potential solution as well.  will report back on what works.  any other tips greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

thanks @wOxxOm, that worked!

i did need to add a couple seconds to the original alarm time to get the comparison to work correctly:

```
chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function(alarm) {
  var currentTime = (new Date).getTime(); 
  var alarmTimePlus = alarm.scheduledTime + 2000
  if (alarmTimePlus > currentTime) {
    showNotification();   // custom function that runs chrome.notifications.create  
  } 
});
```